# How can I find old machine learning deployments now the service has been migrated to Watson Studio?

Tags: data-science-experience, watson-studio, watson-ml

(Also asked on dwAnswers, see: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/447559/view.html)

I created a Machine Learning service several months ago, which has models and deployments associated with it. Now that the Machine Learning service has been integrated into Watson Studio, I can no longer find the deployment.

If I go to the Machine Learning service on IBM Cloud and click 'Access in Watson Studio', I am taken to the Watson Studio overview. For machine learning services which have a project associated, I can view the deployment, however the old service in question is not associated with a project.

What is the best way to find my old deployments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to associate your Machine Learning service instance with one of your projects in Watson Studio by adding it as an "Associated Service" (under the "Settings" tab when viewing the project details).

Once you've done this, the models from your Machine Learning instance will appear on the Project Details Assets tab, and the deployments will appear on the Project Details Deployments tab.